# How do the NBA global games work?

Tags: basketball, nba

Right about now the Indiana Pacers vs Denver Nuggets game will start in London, UK as a part of [NBA Global Games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NBA_Global_Games). I was wondering how this works with who plays at home and who plays away. Since they only play 2 times a year against eachother, won't one team get an advantage since they actually play a game "at home"?

Comment: Probably a fairly minor advantage, considering the 82 games.  Consider that some teams in the NFL, such as the Jaguars, commonly play in England.  Much bigger impact.  Would think they get enough payoff that they consider it worth their while.  The bigger question is: does each team offer discounts on season tickets during the seasons they play those overseas home games.

Comment: Related: [How does the NFL decide which teams play in London?](http://sports.stackexchange.com/q/5826/1723)

Comment: @JeopardyTempest thanks for explaining, I'm just not used to one team having any kind of advantage over the course of a season. Over here(soccer) it's unheard of for a team to even get the slightest advantage . People even complain about matches getting rescheduled because of Europian games

Comment: Except during the Christmas season!  (Only mention it because there ended up being some strong discontent over the uneven rest periods and very short turnarounds in England).  But do agree there's (excessive????) occupation with equality on things like that out there.

Comment: @JeopardyTempest yeah you're right it's also a different mindset. When I go to some facebook comments of a post on a game at the NBA page people complain about the refs when one team get's more free-throws or calls in general. When with soccer most of the time people say one team just plays "dirty", not representative, but it caught my eye. But let's not pretend that those islanders represent the game :)

Comment: Haha, not in England, almost every Bournemouth game I listen to, the commentators complain about the refs.  Or my relatives at least do after the game :-)  But certainly some teams are seen as dirty (though I can think of an NFL and NBA team or two considered to be dirty).  But anyways, think we get off topic!!! :-D